# Xcode4: can't compile sse2 assemble via nasm for x86_64 architecture

Tags: x86-64, nasm, sse2

Currently I'm switching a codec project from 32bit to 64 bit architecture in Xcode4, the *cpp part files are compiling well, but the .asm (all sse2 assemble) files seems can't be compiled into object files at all via nasm (it's OK in 32 bit architecture).
 The clang linker shows errors when linking the sse2 function body (can't find sse2 implement), and I find no objects files output in the obj output folder, any suggestion about this ? my nasm version is 2.10 with 64bits supporting.

Comment: Please include additional information on exactly you're doing and the exact error messages you're seeing.

Comment: the error shows @ link step: "_query_cpuid", reference from: COS::QueryCpuId(int&) in libutils.a, Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64. Clang:error:linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: And I can't find *.o file in output folder/Objects-normal/x86_64/, it's wired that seems the *.asm file contains sse2 code didn't be processed by nasm at all

Comment: I use xcode 4 in Mac10.7 lion 64bits OS, I compiling with 32bit architecture is OK, but meets error in 64bit architecture, any special config needed for nasm for compiling the assemble?

Comment: How are your asm files compiled? Is there some sort of makefile? Can you compile them manually? Are there any errors from NASM?

Comment: I didn't try compiling .asm via nasm manually yet, I setup the xcode project for building all.

Comment: I think xcode + nasm should cover 64bit architecture, maybe I missed somehow to config it right when switching from architecture 32bit to 64bit

Comment: I'm not sure whether xcode or nasm request difference config in 64bit architecture comparing with 32bit architecture

Comment: I just change "Architecture" to "64-bit intel" and "valid architectures" to "x86_64", other config remains the same with 32bit architecture